# Add a column (in Pandas) that is calculated based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple database that has every month's earnings, with `Year` (values 1991-2020), `Month` (Jan-Dec) and `Earnings`. I want to make a new column, where for years 1991-2005 I divide the `Earnings` column by 10000 but for 2006-2020 I want it to be the same as in the earnings column.

I am a beginner, but what I was thinking is that I want the new column (`TrueEarn`) to be `Earnings`/10000 but only for columns 1991-2005.

```
df['TrueEarn'] = df['Earnings']/10000 for (['Year']=('1991':"2005"))
```

Since I am a newb with Python, this may not make sense for you, but that is how I logically wanted to write it

Can you help me, please?

Comment: look up np.where. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoy should provide a  minimum reproducible example. But assuming that you have the year in another column, the way to go could be

```
df['TrueEarn'] = np.where((df['YEAR'] >= 1991) & (df['YEAR'] <= 2005),
                               df['Earnings'] / 10000, df['Earnings'])
```

As @wjandrea says, this can be done directly with pandas, but numpy is faster. Benchmark with a toy dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"YEAR": np.random.randint(1991, 2020, size=50000), "Earnings": np.random.uniform(0, 2e10, size=50000)}
)

   
%timeit df["TrueEarn"] = np.where((df["YEAR"] >= 1991) & (df["YEAR"] <= 2005), df["Earnings"] / 10000, df["Earnings"])
```

695 µs ± 3.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

VS with pandas mask

```
%timeit df["TrueEarn"] = df["Earnings"].mask(df["YEAR"].between(1991, 2005), df["Earnings"] / 10000)
```

959 µs ± 4.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Sergio. Yes, the year is in a sepparate column. The columns are as follows: Year, Month, Earnings. I tried what you reccomended above, but this is the error that it shows me: NameError: name 'np' is not defined.

Comment: If it is a numeric column this should do the trick

Comment: Hey, thanks! It seemed to do the trick, but only after I imported numpy as np. Coult it only work if I import numpy? Is there a way to do it without importing numpy?

Comment: Why use NumPy? Pandas has this built in, BTW you can use `.between()`: `df['TrueEarn'] = df['Earnings'].mask(df['YEAR'].between(1991, 2005), df['Earnings'] / 10000)`. Pandas Series/DataFrame also has [`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html).

Comment: It showed me the error of np being not defined. Only after I googled np error it sait I don't have the numpy imported.

Comment: I think I still lack the basics of what instructions should be addressed where and in what order. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: import packages should be done at the top of your module/script. The same way you have imported pandas to get a dataframe, you should import numpy (or any other package) to use numpy functions